# How to handle when key(s) do not exist in both dicts?

Tags: python, dictionary, keyerror

I'm trying to find a way to merge two dicts, but I'm not getting it to handle with `KeyError`. I already tried to insert a `try`/`except`, `if`s, and nothing works.

This a example of two lists/dicts:

```
list1 = [ {"Name":"Paul", "age": 34, "brothers": ["Sam","Cris","Jack"] } ,
          {"Name":"Evan", "age": 14, "brothers": ["N/A"] } ,
          {"Name":"Loki", "age": 4, "brothers": ["Thor"] }  ]

list2 = {"Sam":["ice_cream"], "Loki": ["cars"], "Jack": ["fruits","cars"],
         "Cris": ["ice_cream"] }
```

Keep in mind that that values are dump of extensive lists, I cannot erase on hands.

What is happening here: There are values which `list2` will not have and some cases, `list1` will show a "N/A".

I'm interested in creating this output: creating a new `info` key and add respective values without repeation, like:

```
[
    {"Name": "Paul", "age": 34, "brothers": ["Sam","Cris","Jack"],
      info: ["icre_cream, "fruis", "cars"]} ,
    {"Name": "Evan", "age": 14, "brothers": ["N/A"], info: []},
    {"Name": "Loki", "age": 4, "brothers": ["Thor"], info: []}
]
```

But trying to iteract, `KeyError` are being raised.

```
newList = [
    {**d, "Ids": sorted(set(i for t in d["brothers"] for i in list2[t]))}
        for d in list1
 ]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```py
def merged(list1, list2):
    new_list = []
    for person in list1:
        extra_info = list(set(sum([list2.get(name, []) for name in person["brothers"]], [])))
        person["info"] = extra_info
        new_list.append(person)
    return new_list
```

The `new_list` list is your expected output.  Note that I called it `list2` here because that's what you named it, but your second input is actually just a dictionary and not a list.

Using `list2.get(name, [])` allows you to return `list2[name]` if the key exists in `list2` and returns `[]` if it doesn't.

Just for kicks since you seem to want a one-liner here, you can define the same `merged` function above like so:

```py
merged = lambda l1, l2: [
    {**d, "info": sum([l2.get(n, []) for n in d["brothers"]], [])} for d in l1
]

newList = merged(list1, list2)
```

**Edit:**

As pointed out in the comments, using `sum` and aggregating the lists before converting them to sets (and back to lists) is very inefficient, albeit more easily readable.  You can use `functools.reduce` to get something more efficient (if you even care):

```py
import functools

merged = lambda l1, l2: [
    {
        **d,
        "info": list(
            functools.reduce(
                lambda a, b: a.union(b),
                [set(l2.get(n, [])) for n in d["brothers"]],
                set(),
            )
        ),
    }
    for d in l1
]
```

Comment: `sum` is horribly inefficient at merging lists since it has to create a new list with copies of items in the existing list for each iteration of merging the next list.

Comment: True, I just figured it was easier to read.  I'll edit to show a less obvious but more efficient way of handling it.

Comment: `reduce` is just as inefficient as `sum` at aggregating containers. It still has to create a new container with copies of items in the existing container for each iteration of aggregating the next container.

Comment: I'm curious what you'd use that's more efficient and uses one line?  Nested list comprehension?
`extra_info = set(info for l in [list2.get(name, []) for name in person["brothers"]] for info in l)`?  Even this requires double storing (and is more inefficient than functools because it will store duplicates until the end).

 
The only thing I can think of is to iteratively pop each sublist off the list and to union them into the set as they're popped off.  But this can't be done in one line and seems rather pedantic, would not be a more pythonic or common approach than either of the above.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a set comprehension with two `for` clauses to merge the info of each brother. Use the `dict.get` method with a default value of an empty tuple to avoid a `KeyError` due to the non-existent key of `'N/A'`:

```
[
    {**d, 'info': sorted({i for b in d['brothers'] for i in list2.get(b, ())})}
    for d in list1
]
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/GlamorousRespectfulWebsphere